# Adding a jpeg image to a post script file

Tags: image, jpeg, postscript

I am trying to read in a jpeg file with java and write it to my post script file.  When I open the post script file with the Acrobat distiller I get an error:

```
%%[ Error: typecheck; OffendingCommand: imageDistiller ]%%

Stack:
{(   Leaving filterIntercept
) --print-- --flush--}
false
/DCTDecode
-dict-
-file-


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

**The following is what my postscript file looks like minus the jpeg data.**

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0

/jpegimage
{173 36 1 [173 0 0 -36 0 36]
{currentfile /ASCII85Decode filter /DCTDecode filter}
image
} bind def

%%Page: 1 1
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 612.0 792.0

100 200 translate
jpegimage
...(jpeg data inline here)...
showpage
%%PageTrailer

%%Trailer
%%EOF
```

Comment: The connection with [tag:java] eludes me, as you haven't posted any Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is using the `proc` form of the `image` call. In this form, the proc must yield a string, not a file.

Try adding `256 string readstring pop` at the end of the proc.

I think you may need to read and discard the jpeg header before the DCT filter gets to the DCT-encoded data.

In the dictionary form `image` will accept a file as a source.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.  What does the dictionary form of image look like?  My intent is to "load" the image once as it could appear multiple times in the PS file.  Would using the dictionary form be a better approach?

Comment: I tried adding:  256 string readstring pop after the filters and before image and that said the OffendingCommand was readstring, when I added it after the image line it said the OffendingCommand was imageDistiller.

Comment: Is the error still a typecheck?  For re-using the file, see the Dec 2002 issue of the [Acumen Journal](http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html) and the next 2 issues for parts 2 and 3.